# Команды для настройки сети ifupdown, ifupdown-ng

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Я новичок в администрировании Linux, только учусь (Читаю книгу Linux_Ot_novichka_k_professionalu_2020_Kolisnichenko.pdf), может ещё какую хорошую книгу посоветуете. Подскажите пожалуйста как пользоваться командами для настройки сети ifupdown, ifupdown-ng, в терминале нет справочной информации для этих команд. Ранее я спрашивал про сервис network,но мне сказали что в Ubuntu 22.04 уже нет сервиса network и посоветовали использовать Файл Пакеты /lib/systemd/system/networking.service ifupdown, ifupdown-ng.

Comment: А тебе чё настроить-то надо?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration

Comment: Да я просто хочу понять как работать с сетью, что такое сервис network и с как им пользоваться через терминал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Его не советовал я использовать, просто отвечал на вопрос в котором было написано что нет networking.service

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полистал книжку - там не networking, а network.

Замените команды вроде `service network restart` на `systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

Команду status смотрите через команду nmcli

```
[eri@eri-macro ~]$ nmcli 
enp5s0: подключено к auto
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8169), A8:A1:59:40:80:EE, аппаратное обеспечение, MTU 1500
        ip4 по умолчанию
        inet4 192.168.117.56/24
        route4 192.168.117.0/24 metric 100
        route4 default via 192.168.117.1 metric 100
        inet6 fe80::37d5:e73c:248:f3b6/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

virbr0: подключено (внешнее) к virbr0
        "virbr0"
        bridge, 52:54:00:02:6B:79, программное обеспечение, MTU 1500
        inet4 192.168.122.1/24
        route4 192.168.122.0/24 metric 0

vlan87: подключено к Соединение VLAN 87
        "vlan87"
        vlan, A8:A1:59:40:80:EE, программное обеспечение, MTU 1500

lo: без управления
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, программное обеспечение, MTU 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 192.168.117.1 85.21.192.3 213.234.192.8
        interface: enp5s0
```

## Про ifupdown

ifupdown это пакет который содержит

- файл конфигурации [/etc/network/interfaces](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=interfaces&category=5&russian=2)
- программы [ifup](https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=ifup&category=8) и [ifdown](https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=ifdown&category=8)
- сервис для настройки сети во время загрузки networking.service

Документация на это https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration . А в книге пара строк со ссылкой в главе 8.7.3

Comment: Я Вас понял. Я начал искать в интернете информацию про ifupdown и про ifupdown-ng, но почему-то не нашёл либо плохо искал. СПАСИБО за пояснение.